# Can I auto login a user on the client that has already been authorized on the server?

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, google-plus, google-oauth

I have an application that uses google's oauth system to authorize with youtube's api. The code for this is done on our server and we receive tokens without any problem. We'd like to move some of the api calls to the client using their [javascript api](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs).

Since we've already authorized the user with the correct scopes required for the youtube api (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube) I assumed when I called authorize on the client it would know that my application was already authorized and allow auto login.  Instead I receive a "immediate_failed" response.  Does anyone know why?  Thanks!

```
gapi.auth.authorize({
    client_id: OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
    scope: OAUTH2_SCOPES,
    immediate: true
}, handleAuthResult);
```

Comment: what happens if you set immediate=false?  Are you sure that scopes are the same? Is the client ID the same, or in the same project, as the server? Is the user logged in to Google?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the token, you can just use [setToken](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiauthsetToken) instead of going through OAuth2 again.